# How to make a check box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Hello. I am totally new to Ruby on Rails and I want to know how to make a **checkbox** or **link_for** in a Ruby on Rails application that will change the value of an attribute called admin in a table called users from false to true , to make the normal user an admin.

NOTE : I am using **form_for** in creating forms

Comment: Please edit your title to be more expressive.

Comment: You should first try to at least read the docs, and test stuff out

Comment: i just followed 9 lessons of michael hartl's tutorial and i am trying to implement what i have done by using what michael hartl made in the 9 lessons into a new rails app ( just i want to try to make my own app not just following a tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read, it explains how to create forms: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like (not tested for syntax):

```
<%= form_for :user do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :admin %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>

<%= end %>
```

in your user model make sure you have:

```
attr :admin
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help me but it doesnt work i got mass-assignment error because in Michael Hartl's tutorial he doesnt write :admin in attr_access for security reasons

Comment: sure, just add an attr for it.