# how to make checkbox in win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, checkbox, win32com

How to create checkbox or checkboxes using Win32 API's?
I don't want to drag and drop check box. I want to create checkbox in WM_CREATE. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Rather than editing an answer into a question that didn't fit the guidelines for the site, you'd do better to spend some time perusing http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  If you'd posted non-working halfway there code, this wouldn't be off topic and wouldn't _be_ closed.

Comment: I asked a simple question, and I wanted to get example, I didn't have that code in the first place, I don't understand what is wrong with question? isn't this question and answer site?

Comment: Not in the sense you're thinking.  This is not an "I don't have anything yet, if I ask someone will do the work for me" site.  This is a "Here's some code I'm having trouble with, can you help me identify the error in either my code, or my thinking, so I can get to the answer myself" site.  Your first attempt didn't have any code, and your second attempt didn't need any help.  Both are outside of the intended scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: If you ever end up with a real question that you answer yourself, don't add the answer to the question, use the "Add Answer" button just like everyone else, and you will get reputation for a good answer just like leaving an answer on someone else's question.  But note that finding an answer doesn't mean that the question was good to being with... :(

Comment: In general, since it is *your problem*, you should be spending more time on it than anyone else.  We will ask you what you've done to help yourself (google, read documentation, try writing and compiling some code)  After you've made an honest effort and still are having trouble, we're glad to help.  You should of course tell us in your question what you've already tried, so we don't simply suggest you do those things all over again ;)

Comment: ... heres a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304422/how-to-make-a-check-box just on ruby-on-rails, why u don't make this also off-topic?   <br/> PS. I cannot post answer if this is marked for closing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the arguments to CreateWindowEx(), the class name should be BUTTON, and the window style should be BS_CHECKBOX.  Both are built-in constants defined in Windows.h

```
hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,BUTTON,"Checkbox",BS_CHECKBOX,xPos,yPos,width,height,parent,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

You would handle it's messages just as you would those from any other window.

Comment: thankyou for suggestions, I made example and if anyone need I posted it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367854(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 7):

According to this link(http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/40147/)

The code should be

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

static char *title = TEXT("Check Box");

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
 MSG  msg ;    
WNDCLASS wc = {0};
wc.lpszClassName = TEXT( "Check Box" );
wc.hInstance     = hInstance ;
wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc ;
wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);


RegisterClass(&wc);
 CreateWindow( wc.lpszClassName, title,
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
            150, 150, 230, 150, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);  

while( GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
TranslateMessage(&msg);
DispatchMessage(&msg);
 }
 return (int) msg.wParam;
}

 LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{

 switch(msg)  
 {
  case WM_CREATE:
  {
    CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Show Title"),
                 WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX,
                 20, 20, 185, 35,        
                 hwnd, (HMENU) 1, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);
    CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);
    break;
  }

  case WM_COMMAND:
  {
       BOOL checked = IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, 1);
    if (checked) {
        CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_UNCHECKED);
     SetWindowText(hwnd, TEXT(""));
    } else {
     CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);
     SetWindowText(hwnd, title);
    }
    break;
   }

  case WM_DESTROY:
  {
       PostQuitMessage(0);
       break;
  }
 }
return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
 }
```

In the forum, they are stating this code is used to create several checkboxes, however a little modification could fix that.

-Happy Programming!

Comment: yes I did read that too, but some of the code was visual c++ I think and some of the code I could not understand, like `LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance` or `(HMENU) 1` theres no such thing like menus in my default created win32 api

Comment: nwm, `(HMENU) 1` is actualy ID of the button

Comment: @Waras If you want to learn Windows programming, Stack Overflow is not a good place to do it. Get yourself a copy of [this classic book](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/).