# WIN32 How to make multiple checkboxes and manage them differently?

Tags: c++, winapi, checkbox

I am trying to write a program in c++ win32 in which i need to have multiple check boxes. To be more specific, this program has multiple "pages" (after the user clicks the next button i delete any child windows and replace them with new ones).
So, to keep the code understandable, i need a function that when is called brings up a couple of fields (i know how to handle those) and some check boxes. The problem is that i don't know how to manage the HWND for each one and so any box i click just runs the same code (and does not check any of the boxes).
MSDN does not offer much help and the only source of information i found was this [how to make checkbox in win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065214/how-to-make-checkbox-in-win32)
This is the part in my code in which the problem arrives.

```
/* checked_box1 , checked_box2 are globals */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam,         
LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
        draw_obtions_screen(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        checked_box1 = IsDlgButtonChecked(draw_object, 1);
        if (checked_box1) {
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_UNCHECKED);
         SetWindowText(hwnd, TEXT("y"));
        } else {
         CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);
         SetWindowText(hwnd,"x");
        }
        checked_box2 = IsDlgButtonChecked(draw_object1, 1);
        if (checked_box2) {
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_UNCHECKED);
         SetWindowText(hwnd, TEXT("Y"));
        } else {
         CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);
         SetWindowText(hwnd,"X");
        }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage (0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

return 0;
}

 ......

/* HWND draw_object,draw_object1 are global. The function is also prev declared*/
void draw_obtions_screen(HWND hwnd)
{
     draw_object = CreateWindow ("BUTTON","check",
                   WS_VISIBLE  | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX,
                   110, 10 ,100 ,30,
                   hwnd, NULL,NULL,NULL);
     CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);

     draw_object1 = CreateWindow ("BUTTON","check another",
                   WS_VISIBLE  | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX,
                   110, 60 ,130 ,30,
                   hwnd, NULL,NULL,NULL);
    CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_UNCHECKED);
}
```

The code changes the title of the window to "X" (on any box i click) and then nothing.

I will apreciate any kind of information source or answer. Also please leave some information sources for me to further learn. Thanks!

Comment: you need not *delete any child windows and replace them with new ones* but have several child's dialog windows, and only one visible at time. when user press *next* or *back* button - you simply make another dialog visible and hide previous. you need associate some data with every child dialog and usually every this dialog have own dialogproc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the child ID through the HMENU parameter to CreateWindowo for any window that has the WS_CHILD style (that is, a child window gets a ID rather than  a menu).

That ID is then sent as part of all the WM_COMMAND messages.